# 32 bit calculator

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation

I'm on an intel 64bit 10.6 osx - and the default calculator application also functions in the same mode. I'd like a 32 bit scientific calculator(with provisions for decimal,bit,hex calculations). Any app suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't do better than trying [PCalc](http://www.pcalc.com/english/about.html) out. It is paid software, but if you look over the reviews and detailed features, you might find it exactly what you want for your programming needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the default Calculator app run in 32-bit mode by getting info on it in the Finder, and selecting the "Open in 32-bit mode" option.  But... why do you care what mode it runs in?

Comment: Oh, no, you seem to have misunderstood my question. Rather than the app running in 32/64 bit more(which i dont really care about) id like 32 bit calculations to occur. its a pain when you wish to find the 2's complement of a number represented in 32 bits but get the answer with 64 and end up manually toggling the leftmost 32 bits. :)